# Union can be done on tables with same no of column In Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is my code:

```
val adf = spark.emptyDataFrame

for (i <- 0 until 10 )
 {
    val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").load("c:\\file.txt") // file has 2 coulmna
    val df2 = spark.read.format("csv").load("c:\\file.txt") // file has 2 coulmna

    df1.creatOrReplaceTempView("tab1")    
    df2.creatOrReplaceTempView("tab2")  

    val res = spark.sql("Select A.* , B.* from tab1 a join tab2 b on a.id = b.id")

    adf =  adf.union(res)
 }

adf.show()
```

Union is failing as it saying "Union can be done on tables with same no of columns"

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by:

Creating Empty Dataframe with Schema:

```
   //Created Schema 
    val schema = StructType(Array
                 (StructField ("Col1",StringType,true),
                 (StructField ("Col2",StringType,true),
                 (StructField ("Col3",StringType,true),
                 (StructField ("Col4",StringType,true)))
    
  //Created EmptyDataFrame
    var adf = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[row],schema)
    
    for (i <- 0 until 10 )
     {
        val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").load("c:\\file.txt") // file has 2 column
        val df2 = spark.read.format("csv").load("c:\\file.txt") // file has 2 coulmna
    
        df1.creatOrReplaceTempView("tab1")    
        df2.creatOrReplaceTempView("tab2")  
    
        val res = spark.sql("Select A.* , B.* from tab1 a join tab2 b on a.id = b.id")    
        adf =  adf.union(res)
     }    
    adf.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Schema of an empty dataframe doesn't have any columns, but your result dataframe has 4 columns, it is the reason why union operation is failing. You can make from adf a variable and use it with null or Option value specified. Example with using Option:

```
var adf: Option[DataFrame] = None

for (i <- 0 until 10 )
 {
    val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").load("c:\\file.txt") // file has 2 coulmsn
    val df2 = spark.read.format("csv").load("c:\\file.txt") // file has 2 coulmsn

    df1.creatOrReplaceTempView("tab1")    
    df2.creatOrReplaceTempView("tab2")  

    val res = spark.sql("Select A.* , B.* from tab1 a join tab2 b on a.id = b.id")
    if (adf.isDefined) {
      adf = Option(adf.get.union(res))
    } else adf = Option(res)
 }
    
    if (adf.isDefined) adf.get.show()
```

Comment: Thanks but `adf.show` outside the loop doesnt work

Comment: Code is failing during Union. Please check once